# How to make image from resource?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I have code that returns me image resource ( it's GD library) like `imagepng($this->image);`.

And Telegram method [sendPhoto](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto).

Please, help me >< what can I do with this resource to send it to Telegram?

Documentation says

> "Photo to send. Pass a file_id as String to send a photo that exists on the Telegram servers (recommended), pass an HTTP URL as a String for Telegram to get a photo from the Internet, or upload a new photo using multipart/form-data. More info on Sending Files »"

But I can't understand what I should make with this resource

Comment: Please check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
Add your code , what have you tried    - and -   `sendPhoto` sends photo.  check [input_type](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputfile)

Answer (score 0):

Method `sendPhoto` has 2 required fields - a `chat_id`, which is usually a user id, and a `photo`. You can specify `photo` using one of [3 following options](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files):

- `URL` of the photo (for example https://telegram.org/img/t_logo.png)
- if you have previously sent your image, you can specify its `file_id`. This option does not make any sense if your bot sends a particular image *only once*. You can obtain `file_id` from `photo` property of [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) object (when you send photo using `sendPhoto` method, the server returns `Message`).
- or you can simply send a photo in HTTP request body using header `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`.

The **easiest** way is to send by `URL`.
The **fastest** way is to send by `file_id`, because telegram servers do not have to process incoming images. That's probably the reason why Telegram API marks it as the *recommended* option.

---

So if have a `URL` of the image, send it by `URL` or by `file_id`. If you have a file, send it as `multipart/form-data` payload.